# Root element getting written multiple times in spring batch

Tags: java, spring, jaxb, spring-batch

I have a requirement of writing a spring batch which reads from a database and writes into XML. I have written the batch, but I'm facing an issue. I have to write XML in the format below,
For example

```xml
<Definition>
  <item>
    <name></name>
  </item>
  <Item>
    <name></name>
  </Item>
</Definition>
```

here `<Definition>` is the root element which should be printed only once and `<item>` can be 1 to n and it is not the root in the xsd. I am using StaxEventItemWriter for this.

I can use headerCallback for `<Definition>` but the problem I am facing is how to set `<item>` in the classesToBeBound as that is not the root element.If somehow I make this as a root then jaxb is inserting default namespace in the xml .
Writer looks like below

````
ItemWriter extends StaxEventItemWriter<item>{
Jaxb2Marshaller marshaller = new Jaxb2Marshaller ();
marshaller .setClassesToBeBound(Item.class);
this.setMarshaller(marshaller );
this.setOverWriteOutput(false);
}```
````

Comment: Have you set the rootTagName: https://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/docs/4.2.x/api/org/springframework/batch/item/xml/StaxEventItemWriter.html#setRootTagName-java.lang.String-? Please share your writer config and your item definition to be able to help you.

Comment: Reframed my question.I hope that helps in understanding the problem

Comment: I added an answer with a complete code example.

Comment: @Ssingh Were you able to solve your problem? I am stuck at similar kind of issue. Need Help.

Answer (score 0):

The root tag should not be written multiple times. Here is a quick example:

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;

import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;

import org.springframework.batch.core.Job;
import org.springframework.batch.core.JobParameters;
import org.springframework.batch.core.configuration.annotation.EnableBatchProcessing;
import org.springframework.batch.core.configuration.annotation.JobBuilderFactory;
import org.springframework.batch.core.configuration.annotation.StepBuilderFactory;
import org.springframework.batch.core.launch.JobLauncher;
import org.springframework.batch.item.ItemReader;
import org.springframework.batch.item.support.ListItemReader;
import org.springframework.batch.item.xml.StaxEventItemWriter;
import org.springframework.batch.item.xml.builder.StaxEventItemWriterBuilder;
import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.core.io.FileSystemResource;
import org.springframework.oxm.jaxb.Jaxb2Marshaller;

@Configuration
@EnableBatchProcessing
public class MyJob {

    @Bean
    public ItemReader<Person> itemReader() {
        List<Person> persons = Arrays.asList(new Person("foo"), new Person("bar"));
        return new ListItemReader<>(persons);
    }

    @Bean
    public StaxEventItemWriter<Person> itemWriter() {
        Jaxb2Marshaller marshaller = new Jaxb2Marshaller();
        marshaller.setClassesToBeBound(Person.class);
        return new StaxEventItemWriterBuilder<Person>()
                .name("personsWriter")
                .rootTagName("persons")
                .resource(new FileSystemResource("persons.xml"))
                .marshaller(marshaller)
                .build();
    }

    @Bean
    public Job job(JobBuilderFactory jobs, StepBuilderFactory steps) {
        return jobs.get("job")
                .start(steps.get("step")
                        .<Person, Person>chunk(5)
                        .reader(itemReader())
                        .writer(itemWriter())
                        .build())
                .build();
    }

    @XmlRootElement
    static class Person {

        private String name;

        public Person() {
        }

        public Person(String name) {
            this.name = name;
        }

        public String getName() {
            return name;
        }

        public void setName(String name) {
            this.name = name;
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        ApplicationContext context = new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext(MyJob.class);
        JobLauncher jobLauncher = context.getBean(JobLauncher.class);
        Job job = context.getBean(Job.class);
        jobLauncher.run(job, new JobParameters());
    }

}
```

If you run this sample, it will generate the following `persons.xml` file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persons>
    <person>
        <name>foo</name>
    </person>
    <person>
        <name>bar</name>
    </person>
</persons>
```

As you can see, the root tag `persons` is written only once. You can find the complete code of the example [here](https://github.com/benas/spring-batch-sandbox/tree/master/so60118873).

Comment: Thank you for taking a look . The xml which I am writing is based on xsd,in that 
``` <item>``` (from the question I posted) is not the root-element now if I make this as root then jaxb insert some default namespace like ns2 in the generated xml which I don't want.I tried doing this but not getting the desired output.